# How to fit image in UITextView and Tap to get larger

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have created a Table-view in main ViewController once i touch the row it will take to the next view controller(DetailViewController) where it display the image and name of dish.And once i tap the image it should get larger but it is not getting bigger .The below code is which i have tried in DetailViewController.

DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,100, 100)];
CGRect textViewFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 400);
textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewFrame];
textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
textView.editable=NO;
textView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textView]; 
[textView addSubview:imageView];
textView.alpha = 0.9;
textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

if(mrowno==0)
{
     imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dosa.jpg"];  
    textView.text = @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nDOSA\nDosa, ";
    imageButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    [imageButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [imageView addSubview:imageButton];

}
```

Here is the method to make image larger

```
-(void)imageTapped:(UIButton*)in_sender
{


[UIView transitionWithView:in_sender.superview  duration:0.8f  options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear  animations:^
 {  
     [in_sender.superview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 500)];
 }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) 
 {
 }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase and decrease the size of image by pinch in and pinch out,If it required

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
 { 
 UIPinchGestureRecognizer* pinch=[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self            action:@selector(pinching:)];
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinch];
  }

-(void)pinching:(UIGestureRecognizer*) recognizer
 {
UIPinchGestureRecognizer* pinch=(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*) recognizer;
self.imageView.transform=CGAffineTransformScale(self.imageView.transform, pinch.scale, pinch.scale);
pinch.scale=1;
NSLog(@"pinching");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use `transitionWithView`. Instead, you want to use `+ animateWithDuration: delay:options:animations:completion:` (or any of its shorter variants...)

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    viewYouWantToAnimate.frame = CGRectMake(..., ..., ..., ...);
} completion:^{
    //Add completion code here, or pass nil if you don't have anything to do.
}];
```

Edit: In case you were wondering what transitionWithView was used for... the [AppleDocs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) have a great example of it adding animations for remove/addSubview methods (not frame modifications):

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
       duration:0.2
       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
       animations:^{
           [fromView removeFromSuperview];
           [containerView addSubview:toView];
       } completion:NULL];
```